# Adding count and percent to bars ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, count, percentage

I have added counts to the top of bars, but cannot figure out how to add % in brackets next to the count! My attempts return `prop*100` next to the count above the bar. Here is my code that generates count only - what do I need to modify to this to add the %?

```
df %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = day_of_week, fill = day_of_week)) +
    geom_bar(position = "dodge") +
    geom_text(aes(label = ..count..), stat = "count", vjust = -1.0, colour = "black") +
    ylim(0, 2600) +
    theme_classic() +
    theme(legend.position="none",
           axis.text.x = element_text(angle=45, hjust=1)
          ) +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = 1, direction = - 1) +
    xlab("day_of_week") +
    ylab("Count (n)")
```

Comment: Well, I came across to this question before. My suggestion is that you can add a new colnum into your data `df` like **2(5%)** and add the colnum to your barplot through `geom_text`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an option without creating a new column:

```
df %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = day_of_week, fill = day_of_week)) +
  geom_bar(position = "dodge") +
  geom_text(aes(label = paste0(..count..,"(",round(..count..*100/nrow(df)), "%)")), stat = "count", vjust = -1.0, colour = "black") +
  ylim(0, 2600) +
  theme_classic() +
  theme(legend.position="none",
        axis.text.x = element_text(angle=45, hjust=1)
  ) +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = 1, direction = - 1) +
  xlab("day_of_week") +
  ylab("Count (n)")
```

[image]

And here is an option with a new column created before the plot:

```
df %>% group_by(day_of_week) %>%
  summarise(n =n())%>%
  mutate(pct= round(n/sum(n)*100, digit=0))%>%
  ggplot(aes(x = day_of_week, y = n, fill = day_of_week)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  geom_text(aes(label = paste0(n, " (",pct, "%)")), vjust = -1.0, colour = "black") +
  ylim(0, 2600) +
  theme_classic() +
  theme(legend.position="none",
        axis.text.x = element_text(angle=45, hjust=1)
  ) +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = 1, direction = - 1) +
  xlab("day_of_week") +
  ylab("Count (n)")
```

[image]

#### Data

---

```
set.seed(14) 
df = data.frame(day_of_week = factor(sample(c("Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat", "Sun"),
                                     size = 3000,
                                     prob = c(1,3,5,2,6,10,1),
                                     replace = TRUE), levels = c("Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat", "Sun")))
```

Comment: This is perfect, exactly what I was trying to create! Thank you!

Comment: Glad I could help you improve your skills! If your question has been answered, please make sure to accept an answer for further references.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up create a new col with a count of each category of interest and ran the code below!

```
df2 <- df %>%
  select(day_of_week) %>%
  group_by(day_of_week) %>% 
  mutate(count_day_of_week_group = n()) %>%
  ungroup

df2 <- df2 %>%  
  distinct(count_day_of_week_group, .keep_all = TRUE)

ggplot(df2, aes(x = day_of_week, y = count_day_of_week_group)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", color = "black", fill = "dodgerblue1") +
  geom_text(label = with(df2, 
                         sprintf("%d (%.0f%%)", 
                                 count_day_of_week_group, 100*count_day_of_week_group/sum(count_day_of_week_group))), 
            vjust=-1)+
  ylim(0,3000)
```